# PowerShell search and replace

Tags: search, powershell

I have about 500 filenames in a .txt file without the extensions. I have another .txt file with full filenames with extensions that total over 1,000.

I need to loop through the smaller .txt file and search for the current line being read in the bigger .txt file. If it's found then copy the name to a new file, `found.txt`,  and if it's not then move on to the next line in the smaller .txt file.

I am new to scripting and don't really know here to start.

```
Get-childitem -path "C:\Users\U0146121\Desktop\Example" -recurse -name | out-file C:\Users\U0146121\Desktop\Output.txt  #send filenames to text file
(Get-Content C:\Users\U0146121\Desktop\Output.txt) |
ForEach-Object {$_  1
```

Comment: Could you add some sample input and what you want for output? It would help us understand the question better.

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you want to achieve by doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example shows you creating the text file by recursing through a folder on the desktop. You don't need a text file to loop through; you could just use that, but let’s say you do generate the text file of a short name like you state.

```
$short_file_names = Get-Content C:\Path\To\500_Short_File_Names_No_Extensions.txt
```

Now you can loop through that array in two ways:

Using the `foreach` keyword:

```
foreach ($file_name in $short_file_names) {
    # ...
}
```

Or using the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet:

```
$short_file_names | ForEach-Object {
    # ...
}
```

The big difference is that the current item will be a named variable `$file_name` in the first and a non-named built-in `$_` variable in the second.

Let's say you use the first. You need to see if `$file_name` is in the second file and if so record that you found it. It can be done this way. I've put comments in the code explaining each part.

```
# Read the 1000 names into an array variable
$full_file_names = Get-Content C:\Path\To\1000_Full_File_Names.txt

# Loop through the short file names and test each
foreach ($file_name in $short_file_names) {

    # Use the -match operator to check if the array contains the string
    # The -contains operator won't work since its a partial string match due to the extension
    # Need to escape the file name since the -match operator uses regular expressions

    if ($full_file_names -match [regex]::Escape($file_name)) {

        # Record the discovered item
        $file_name | Out-File C:\Path\To\Found.txt -Encoding ASCII -Append
    }
}
```